# Error for Maven Structure in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy

Setting:

- Eclipse Neon 3.
- Embedded Maven 3.3.9
- Settings xml configured with proxy
- Root maven project call "root" with packaging "pom"
- Child module with a war called "rest"
- Override of the maven repositories to use HTTP
- Build is working - target folder contains the artifact
- Libraries are stored in the .m2
- Plugin libraries are stored in the .m2

Problem:
Eclipse displays only folders in the package structure and does not reorganize the structure with the normal hierarchy (src/main/java , src/main/resources, ... target, pom.xml). I'm getting a strange error when I tell maven to update the project:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". Unable to
>   provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor,
>   java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
>   implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)   at
>   io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.(Unknown
>   Source)   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules:
>   org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule ->
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)   while locating
>   io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory   while
>   locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
>
> 1 error

I hope you have an idea. Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 0):

Moved to Eclipse Oxygen and the error is gone. Sry about the question. It was my last hope.